# Getting an error "Expected a MKTileOverlay but got (null)" when trying to add MKTileOverlay object to MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mktileoverlay

`MKMapView` class is added and assigned delegate:

```
let mapView: MKMapView = {

    let map = MKMapView()
    map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return map
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {

self.view.addSubview(mapView)

    mapView.delegate = self

let center = mapView.centerCoordinate

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

Then the `mapView` is assigned `center` coordinate and span is set. `zoomLevel` is set to 1

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0, longitudeDelta: 360 / pow(2, Double(zoomLevel)) * Double(mapView.frame.size.width) / 256)
        setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span), animated: animated)
```

// I wrote URL like this because I was told that `MKTileOverlay` class will take care of `z`, `x`, and `y` value.

```
let urlTemplate = "https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid={my API ID}"
```

// `urlTemplate` is added to `MKTileOverlay`

```
            let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: urlTemplate)

            overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
```

// And just when I am about to add `overlay` to `mapView`, the app will crash:

```
self.mapView.addOverlay(overlay)
```

// It takes me to `AppDelegate.swift` and then it shows this message:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "Expected a MKTileOverlay but got (null)"
```

Everything was added to `viewDidLoad()`.

I also added `renderedFor` delegate functions. Like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    var renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer()

    print("overlay rendered For: \(overlay)")

    if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
        renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay:overlay)
        renderer.alpha = 0.8
    }

    return renderer
}
```

Comment: I tried to put number in x, y, z values to see if URL is valid. I typed it in, and it's working. So server is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what was causing the crash for me was the initialisation of `MKTileOverlayRenderer()` without specifying an overlay.

So basically, your code inside the `mapView(_:rendererFor:)` delegate method should be:

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    print("overlay rendered For: \(overlay)")

    if let overlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay {
        renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.alpha = 0.8
        return renderer.alpha
    } else {
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }

}
```